# Best validation method for a dynamic class in java (Micronaut)

Tags: java, validation, micronaut

I have a class `A` (listed below) which can have many different types of attributes saved to it. Naturally these attributes can be of different types. Based on the type of attribute I want to apply some validations to it.

What would be the best way of doing it in Micronaut?

Here is an example of what I want to achieve:

```java
public class A {
    
    private String type;
    private String value;

    // getter/setter omitted…
}
```

Some example instances of class A:

```json
{type: "type1", value: "examplevalue1"}
```

```json
{type: "type2", value: "examplevalue2"}
```

```json
{type: "type2", value: "examplevalue3"}
```

Then I have some set of validation rules which are relevant to the respective types. Each type (`type1`, `type2`, `type3`) have separate set of validation rules. These rules are not just restricted to String validation but also semantic and business validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve this using specific class per type. You can introduce an interface `A`

```java
interface A {
   String getType();
}
```

and then implement the concrete types.

```java
public class Type1 implements A {

    @NotBlank
    private String value;

    @Override
    public String getValue() { return this.value; }

    public void setValue(String v) { this.value = v; }
}
```

```java
public class Type2 implements A {

    @YourCustomValidator
    private String value;

    @Override
    public String getValue() { return this.value; }

    public void setValue(String v) { this.value = v; }
}
```

and then implement a custom Jackson Deserializer which is able to build an instance of `A` by inspecting the JSON string field `type`.

I don't think that Drools has anything to do with this question.

Comment: Thank you so much for a quick response. I did think of a solution you presented but there was a little problem, why I didn't go with it. The number of types in my case are many (more than 100). How would you address this?

Comment: If you have different business logic for each type you will need to implement this anyway

Comment: That is correct.